# PowerShell pscmdlet unit testing with C#

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-core

Need some help understanding how to unit test a PowerShell module I'm creating.

I'm using the PowerShellStandard.Library package to create some cmdlets. My commands are deriving from pscmdlet and not cmdlet since I do need to manipulate the SessionState variables.

I've created a new unit testing project and I've searched some tutorials (e.g. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TestingPowerShellScriptsWithNUnit.aspx) where I found that I do need to use the Runspace class in order to execute the pscmdlet. Problem is that the below command, always returns a null runspace:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2());
```

Anyone have been experimenting with these lately and have any idea?

Comment: Have you looked into Pester?  It's a PowerShell native unit testing module

Comment: @BryceMcDonald, thanks for the comment. I've come across that. Unfortunately doesn't seem what I need though, because the pscmdlet is csharp code and I would like to test inside VS, meaning I would like to breakpoint into the execution of the cmdlets. May be wrong but it seems that Pester deals with the "final thing" and runs inside PowerShell. It may be also useful but not for the exact thing that I need.

Comment: Yeah, Pester would be for the finalized C# module.  Technically they'd be more or less "Integration tests" at that point.  How do you normally do unit testing with C#?  Wouldn't you just follow the same methods?  You may try asking the question in the C# SO channels

Comment: for typical cmdlets, there's a nice post that shows how to unit test them with c#: https://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/PowerShellUnitTestCmdlet. The problem here is that I'm trying to create Pscmdlet and not the base cmdlet, which require the instantiation of a runspace.

Answer (score 2):

I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696574/how-to-unit-test-a-powershell-core-binary-cmdlet-in-c-sharp) and the issue ended up being that I was trying to use the `PowerShellStandard.Library` NuGet package as well. Instead, you want to use the [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) NuGet package.

I also have [an example repo](https://github.com/deadlydog/PowerShellCmdletInCSharpExample) setup that shows how to run xUnit tests against a C# PowerShell Core cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get it working with a Runspace but I was able to unit test my PSCmdlets. Unfortunately, the solution I found wasn't very satisfying. I added a method to expose `ProcessRecord` like so:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "AnExample")]
public class ExampleCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    public void ProcessInternal()
    {
        ProcessRecord();
    }
}
```

When invoking the PSCmdlet from a unit test, I'd use this method:

```
var cmdlet = new ExampleCmdlet();
var proxy = new CommandRuntimeProxy();
cmdlet.CommandRuntime = proxy;
cmdlet.ProcessInternal();
var results = proxy.WrittenObjects.Select(obj => (T) obj).ToList();
```

`CommandRuntimeProxy` is a new class that receives the objects. Here are the important parts, but there are more methods to implement.

```
internal class CommandRuntimeProxy : ICommandRuntime
{
    public List<object> WrittenObjects { get; } = new List<object>();

    public bool ShouldContinue(string query, string caption)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool ShouldProcess(string target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error in pipeline", errorRecord.Exception);
    }

    public void WriteError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error in pipeline", errorRecord.Exception);
    }

    public void WriteObject(object sendToPipeline, bool enumerateCollection)
    {
        WriteObject(sendToPipeline);
    }

    public void WriteObject(object sendToPipeline)
    {
        WrittenObjects.Add(sendToPipeline);
    }
}
```

Effectively, you bypass most of the Powershell pipeline with this method. It seems to work reasonably well so far, so long as you use your hide access to the Powershell runtime behind interfaces for the benefit of your tests.

I believe the reason it's like this is because Powershell is quite a bit older and might not have seen quite as much love as the more recent MVC offerings from Microsoft. I hope this will change one day, but this is reasonable enough for now.

Comment: Good Idea. This can also be achieved by using Moq.