# How to unit test a PowerShell Core binary cmdlet in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, unit-testing, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-core

I've written a [simple PowerShell cmdlet in C#](https://github.com/deadlydog/PowerShellCmdletInCSharpExample) to show off the problem I'm encountering. Feel free to clone the repo, or fork it and get it working and submit a PR, or just look at the source code to see exactly what I am doing.

I've created a simple PowerShell Core cmdlet using [the PowerShellStandard.Library NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library). I'm using xUnit and am trying to run a unit test against the PowerShell cmdlet that I've created. The problem is that when I call the `.Invoke()` method of the cmdlet instance, it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Here's the cmdlet I've created:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "RepeatedString")]
[OutputType(typeof(string))]
public class GetRepeatedStringCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    [Alias("Word")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    public string Phrase { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    [Alias("Repeat")]
    public int NumberOfTimesToRepeatPhrase { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTimesToRepeatPhrase; i++)
        {
            result.Append(Phrase);
        }

        WriteObject(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a unit test I'm trying to run:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldReturnThePhraseRepeatedTheCorrectNumberOfTimes()
{
    // Arrange.
    var phrase = "A test phrase.";
    int numberOfTimesToRepeat = 3;
    var cmdlet = new GetRepeatedStringCmdlet()
    {
        Phrase = phrase,
        NumberOfTimesToRepeatPhrase = numberOfTimesToRepeat
    };
    var expectedResult = Enumerable.Repeat(phrase, numberOfTimesToRepeat);

    // Act.
    var enumerator = cmdlet.Invoke().GetEnumerator(); // NullReferenceException thrown here when calling .Invoke().
    Assert.True(enumerator.MoveNext());
    var results = enumerator.Current;

    // Assert.
    Assert.Equal(results, expectedResult);
}
```

When I test the script in PowerShell it does appear to work correctly:

```
ImportModule .\PowerShellCmdletInCSharpExample.dll
Get-RepeatedString -Phrase "Hello there" -NumberOfTimesToRepeatPhrase 3
Hello thereHello thereHello there
```

I'm following examples I've found on some blog posts, [like this one](https://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/PowerShellUnitTestCmdlet) and [this one](https://keithbabinec.com/2019/05/01/tips-for-writing-your-first-compiled-binary-powershell-modules/), but I guess they don't have this issue when calling `.Invoke()`. Other blog posts, [like this one](https://d-fens.ch/2016/11/16/unit-testing-c-binary-powershell-modules/), use a `PsCmdletAssert` class to `.Invoke()` the cmdlet, but that class does not seem to exist in the `PowerShellStandard.Library` NuGet package, so I'm guessing it's a not a PowerShell Core friendly class. [Other blogs](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2013/04/unit-testing-powershell-commandlet.html) create a new runspace and pipeline on every test execution, but again, I don't seem to have the `CreatePipeline()` function when using the PowerShellStandard library.

So my question is, how can I run xUnit tests against my PowerShell Core `Cmdlet`s that I create in C# in order to verify they function as expected?

Thanks in advance!

---

### Update

Using the .Net Framework version of the `System.Management.Automation.dll` does not throw an exception when `Invoke()`ing the cmdlet, so my work around has been to define my unit test project as a .Net Framework project, instead of .Net Core. This has allowed me to unit test the cmdlet as expected using the code shown in this post. The cmdlet is still defined in a .Net Core project and is cross-platform, only the unit tests are not.

Currently the latest version of the `PowerShellStandard.Library` NuGet package is 5.1.0, so hopefully this issue gets addressed in a future version.

Comment: I Googled for `PsCmdletAssert.cs` and found this:

https://github.com/dfch/biz.dfch.CS.Testing/blob/develop/src/biz.dfch.CS.Testing/PowerShell/PsCmdletAssert.cs

Comment: Thanks @JonathanGilbert. It looks like that is using `RunspaceConfiguration` which has a dependency on the `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies` NuGet package, which is not using .Net Standard; it requires at least .Net Framework 4.6.1, and thus is not cross-platform compatible. I guess it's not the end of the world, since I would only need to include the reference in my unit test project, but I would still like to find a truly cross-platform solution to this problem so I can run unit tests on non-Windows machines/containers.

Comment: MS recently blogged about the various PowerShell project types and which NuGet packages to use for them: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/depending-on-the-right-powershell-nuget-package-in-your-net-project/

Comment: I thought .NET 4.6.1 _was_ .NET Standard-compatible.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Qq0LbBQ.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced this same problem. I was able to resolve this by installing [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) into my unit test project, whereupon my `Cmdlet.Invoke()` and `Powershell.Create()` calls began working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I've also blogged about the process of creating and testing PowerShell Core cmdlets in C# at https://blog.danskingdom.com/Create-and-test-PowerShell-Core-cmdlets-in-CSharp/

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I experienced the same issue - even though I had added Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK to my test project. My problem was that my Test project was using .NET6, but I had added PowerShell.SDK 7.3.3, which requires .NET7. Updating my test project to .NET7 resolved it for me.